# Split this values part of an insert query

Tags: php, regex

Is there any way to achieve the following? I need to take this $query and split it into its various elements (the reason is because I am having to reprocess an insert query). As you can see this will work for regular string blocks or numbers, but not where a number, occurs in the string. Is there a way to say |\d but not where that \d occurs within a ' quoted string '?

```
$query = "('this is\'nt very, funny (I dont think)','is it',12345,'nope','like with 2,4,6')";

$matches = preg_split("#',|\d,#",substr($query,1,-1));

echo $query;   
print'<pre>[';print_r($matches);print']</pre>';
```

So just to be clear about expected results:

```
0:'this is\'nt very, funny (I dont think)'
1:'it is'
2:12345
3:'nope'
4:'like with 2,4,6'.
```

** Additionally I don't mind if each string is *not* quoted - I can requote them myself.

Comment: provide expected "output" (`$matches`).

Comment: $matches would be split at each field/value separating , as opposed to comma's found within strings. So split at , but not every one.

Comment: if you provide output users can try to verify that their understanding of the *textual* description is correct. nobody likes fuzzy descriptions. create good examples that show the *behavior* for *corner cases*.

Comment: @Ukuser32 post the expected output in your question.

Comment: Please see my response. I would expect each of the following to be values in the array: 0:'this is\'nt very, funny (I dont think)', 1:'it is', 2:12345, 3:'nope', 4:'like with 2,4,6'. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Ukuser32 fantastic question, Could you post the above comment in your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could [(*SKIP)(*F)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Special-Backtracking-Control-Verbs) parts that are inside single quotes and match `,` outside:

```
'(?:\\'|[^'])*'(*SKIP)(*F)|,
```

`(?:\\'|[^'])` Inside the single quotes matches escaped `\'` or a character that is not a single quote.

[See Test at regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/pL1zJ0/2)

```
$query = "('this is\'nt very, funny (I dont think)','is it',12345,'nope','like with 2,4,6')";

$matches = preg_split("~'(?:\\\\'|[^'])*'(*SKIP)(*F)|,~", substr($query,1,-1));

print_r($matches);
```

[outputs to](https://eval.in/207916) (test at eval.in)

```
Array
(
    [0] => 'this is\'nt very, funny (I dont think)'
    [1] => 'is it'
    [2] => 12345
    [3] => 'nope'
    [4] => 'like with 2,4,6'
)
```

Not absolutely sure, if that is what you mean :)

Comment: that's what OP is looking for i guess :)

Comment: That is 100% what I was after. Thanks and I don't think I'd have got there in a million years (well maybe a few hundred)!!

Answer (score 1):

```
('(?:(?!(?<!\\)').)*')|(\d+)
```

Try this.Grab the captures.Each string is quoted as well.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dK1xR4/3

Comment: Unfortunately `preg_split("#('(?:(?!(?<!\\)').)*')|(\d+)#gm",substr($query,1,-1));` does not work?

Comment: How would you implement this in php? Because i have a regex also but it fails when executing the regex along with the code.

Comment: @Ukuser32 use `preg_match_all` and then grab the groups. No need of `m` flag

Answer (score 1):

You could try matching through `preg_match_all` instead of splitting.

```
<?php
$data = "('this is\'nt very, funny (I dont think)','is it',12345,'nope','like with 2,4,6')";
$regex = "~'(?:\\\\'|[^'])+'|(?<=,|\()[^',)]*(?=,|\))~";
preg_match_all($regex, $data, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 'this is\'nt very, funny (I dont think)'
    [1] => 'is it'
    [2] => 12345
    [3] => 'nope'
    [4] => 'like with 2,4,6'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using `preg_match`, then the solution could look like this. This regex uses lookbehind with negative assertions `(?<!\\\\)`, it will match strings inside quotes that is not preceded by slash, and the alternation with the vertical bar ensures that numbers that are part of larger match will be ignored.

```
$query = "('this is\'nt very, funny (I dont think)','is it',12345,'nope','like with 2,4,6',6789)";  

preg_match_all( "/(?<!\\\\)\'.+?(?<!\\\\)\'|\d+/", substr( $query, 1, -1 ), $matches );

print_r( $matches );
/* output: 
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'this is\'nt very, funny (I dont think)'
            [1] => 'is it'
            [2] => 12345
            [3] => 'nope'
            [4] => 'like with 2,4,6'
            [5] => 6789
        )

)
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
,(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)
```

Try this.This will split according to what you want.Replace by `\n`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dK1xR4/4