# Endline after certain number of characters

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, text-files

I have a text file with a lot of inserts that looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO yyy VALUES ('1','123123','da,sdadwa','6.7','24f,5','f5,5','dasdad,fsdfsdfsfsasada dasdasd','aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa','dasdasd','q231e','','0','','g','1','123123','dasdadwa','6.7','24f,5','f5,5','dasdad,fsdfsdfsfsasada dasdasd','','','q231e','','0','','a','1','123123','dasdadwa','655.755','24f,5','f5,5','dasdad,fsdfsdfsfsasada dasdasd','','','q231e','','','','a');
INSERT INTO yyy VALUES ('2','123123','dasdadwa','6.8','24f,6','f5,5','dasdad,fsdfsdfsfsasada dasdasd','aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa','dasdasd','q231e','','0','','g','2','123123','dasdadwa','6.8','24f,6','f5,5','dasdad,fsdfsdfsfsasada dasdasd','','','q231e','','0','','a','2','123123','dasdadwa','6.8','24f,6','f5,5','dasdad,fsdfsdfsfsasada dasdasd','','','q231e','','','','a');
INSERT INTO yyy VALUES ('3','123123','dasdadwa','6.9','24f,7','f5,5','dasdad,fsdfsdfsfsasada dasdasd','aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa','dasdasd','q231e','','0','','g','3','123123','dasdadwa','6.9','24f,7','f5,5','dasdad,fsdfsdfsfsasada dasdasd','','','q231e','','0','','a','3','123123','dasdadwa','6.9','24f,7','f5,5','dasdad,fsdfsdfsfsasada dasdasd','','','q231e','','','','a');
INSERT INTO yyy VALUES ('4','123123','dasdadwa','6.10','24f,8','f5,5','dasdad,fsdfsdfsfsasada dasdasd','aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa','dasdasd','q231e','','0','','g','4','123123','dasdadwa','6.10','24f,8','f5,5','dasdad,fsdfsdfsfsasada dasdasd','aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa','','q231e','','0','','a','4','123123','dasdadwa','6.10','24f,8','f5,5','dasdad,fsdfsdfsfsasada dasdasd','aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa','','q231e','','','','a');
INSERT INTO yyy VALUES ('5','123123','dasdadwa','6.11','24f,9','f5,5','dasdad,fsdfsdfsfsasada dasdasd','aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa','dasdasd','q231e','','0','','g','5','123123','dasdadwa','6.11','24f,9','f5,5','dasdad,fsdfsdfsfsasada dasdasd','aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa','','q231e','','0','','a','5','123123','dasdadwa','6.11','24f,9','f5,5','dasdad,fsdfsdfsfsasada dasdasd','aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa','','q231e','','','','a');
```

I must modify this text file so that each line can have a maximum of 50 characters. The problem is that I cannot simply put an endline after 50 characters because that would break the elements in those inserts, so I need to put the endline before the last comma.

For the first row it needs to be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO yyy VALUES ('1','123123','da,sdadwa',
'6.7','24f,5','f5,5',
'dasdad,fsdfsdfsfsasada dasdasd',
'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
'dasdasd','q231e','','0','','g','1','123123',
'dasdadwa','6.7','24f,5','f5,5',
'dasdad,fsdfsdfsfsasada dasdasd','','','q231e','',
'0','','a','1','123123','dasdadwa','655.755',
'24f,5','f5,5','dasdad,fsdfsdfsfsasada dasdasd',
'','','q231e','','','','a');
```

As you can see there can be commas even inside the elements('da,sdadwa') which makes this a tad more difficult. I tried putting everything into arrays but I ran into some problems and couldn't get it to work.
What  i tried:

```
if(is_array($testFileContents))
    {
        foreach($testFileContents as $line)
        {
            $j=0;
            for($i=0;$i<=strlen($line);$i++)
            {
                //echo $line[$i];
                $ct=1;
                if($j==50)
                {
                    if($line[$j]==",")
                    {
                        //$line[$j]=$line[$j].PHP_EOL;
                    }   
                    else
                    {
                        $temporaryJ = $j;
                        while($line[$temporaryJ]!=",")
                        {
                            $temporaryJ--;
                        }
                        //$line[$temporaryJ] = $line[$temporaryJ].PHP_EOL;
                        //$j=$i-$ct*50;
                        $j=0;
                        $ct=$ct+1;
                        echo $ct." ";
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    $j++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I know there has to be a much more simple way of going around this without using arrays but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: This may help http://jdorn.github.io/sql-formatter/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [preg_split()](http://php.net/preg_split) to split the lines. I found a pattern another user posted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26464592/split-this-values-part-of-an-insert-query#answer-26465171) for matching values for an INSERT statement:
    `"~'(?:\\\\'|[^'])*'(*SKIP)(*F)|,~"`. This utilizes [Special Backtracking Control Verbs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Special-Backtracking-Control-Verbs).

You can play with the PHP code in [this PhpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/3jb4-b5e1).

```
foreach($lines as $line) {
    $matches = preg_split("~'(?:\\\\'|[^'])*'(*SKIP)(*F)|,~",$line);
    $currentIndex = 0;
    $currentLine = '';
    $outputLines = array();
    $delimeter = ',';
    while($currentIndex < count($matches)) {
        if ($currentIndex == count($matches)-1 ) {
            $delimeter = '';
        }
        $tempLine = $currentLine . $matches[$currentIndex] . $delimeter;
        if (strlen($tempLine) <= 50) {
            $currentLine .= $matches[$currentIndex] . $delimeter;
        }
        else {//push current line into array and start a new line
            $outputLines[] = $currentLine;
            $currentLine = $matches[$currentIndex] . $delimeter;
        }
        if ($currentIndex == count($matches)-1 ) {
            $outputLines[] = $currentLine;
        }
        $currentIndex++;
    }
    //can use implode("\n",$outputLines) to write out to file 
    //or whatever your needs are
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! This really helped. I still have a hard finding a comprehensive and easy to understand regex tutorial online. Do you happen to know a good one?

Comment: Good. I haven't gone through all of [regexone.com](https://regexone.com/) but it looks decent with the interactive exercises, and  I often refer to [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) as a reference...

Comment: Ok. I will check them out!